# How to get deployed jars in Jboss

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee

How can I get the list of jars deployed in JBoss?

I want to compile some classes at runtime in EJB, but they may use some of the deployed jars, so I need to specify classpath during compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to list deployed applications using the [ProfileService ManagementView](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ProfileServiceManagementView). Check the various methods of [`org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.ManagementView`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.com/maven2/org.jboss.integration/jboss-profileservice-spi/6.0.0.Alpha6/org/jboss/deployers/spi/management/ManagementView.java#ManagementView.getDeploymentNames%28%29).